# Not able to fetch gerrit created date of review

Tags: java, gerrit

I am using gerrit REST API to fetch the changes.
Is there any way by which i can fetch the reviews based on created date?

There is only an option to fetch based on updated date as i see.

```
gerritApi.changes().query("before +"time+"+after:"time)
```

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no way to query based on created date. You could try to workaround this by querying based on other parameter (like project, owner, reviewer, etc) and then use the "created" field of the JSON response to select what you want. See more info [here](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/rest-api-changes.html#list-changes).